# Ubuntu does not use DNS server from router

Tags: ubuntu, dns, resolv.conf

I cannot solve DNS resolution on UBUNTU 20.04. If I check the IP values after connection it is showing the right DNS server address, but in NSLookup the DNS server is not listed, and it comes back with a connection problem.

When I change over to my phone's hotspot as WIFI connection, the DNS server from the DHCP server is showing up and working properly.

On any other computer, running MacOS or Windows or Android no issue with the router settings. Only the Ubuntu installation is not working properly.

I have checked several posts and tried to add nameservers manually to /etc/resolv.conf (its linked file, of course), but nothing works for me.

Comment: Can you please post your resolv.conf  here, and specify if your router has a static DNS or the one it grabs from ISP DHCP?

Comment: I have set the DNS manually on my modem and get dynamically on my router. But I have tried to set manually on the router as well. On both ways I have no problem with other computers, running Windows or MacOS or our phones either Android or iOS. Just on Linux, even with different distros.

Comment: Actually in /etc/resolv.conf I see my router's address as "name server 192.168.31.1".

Comment: So modem is your way to the internet and the router is there to share it across all devices? 
I suggest you to either test setting _"name server 192.168.31.1"_ or try setting your modem ip as a nameserver

Comment: I have the feeling that it is a driver issue. I have installed Linux on my MacBook Air 2018 and it works without any issue. I have planned to install Linux on my outdated MacBook 2004 which still works fine, just no MacOS updated since years now, but it is 64bit Core2Duo type, so still capable for few things. :) But this Wifi issue is disturbing. :)